PayPal API - How to track back the user when the user goes through the Onboarding process
I have managed to get the access token, and use that access token to create a "partner-referrals". Then managed to get the "action_url" and add this "action_url" to the button as shown below. The @(Model) is where the "action_url" is added":
        <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
        <script>
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, ref = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.async = true;
                    js.src = "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/merchantboarding/js/lib/lightbox/partner.js";
                    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                }
            }(document, "script", "paypal-js"));
        </script>
        <a data-paypal-button="true" href="@(Model)&displayMode=minibrowser" target="PPFrame">Sign up for PayPal</a>
    </div>

When I use a sandbox account to sign in, I was shown on YouTube that from the payload that was sent before displaying the "action_url" the "tracking_id" can be used to get back the "merchant_id" which would be stored in the database. But I cant find in the documentation what API to use to get back the sellers data and store the sellers data when onboarding.
I don't understand what I need to use, it says in the partner referrals documentaion is that you need to use the "partner_referral_id" and the only way to get this as i noticed before i got the "action_url", this was the response:
{
    "links": [
       {
           "href": "https://uri.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals/ZjcyODU4ZWYtYTA1OC00ODIwLTk2M2EtOTZkZWQ4NmQwYzI3RU12cE5xa0xMRmk1NWxFSVJIT1JlTFdSbElCbFU1Q3lhdGhESzVQcU9iRT0=",
           "rel": "self",
           "method": "GET"
       },
       {
           "href": "https://www.paypal.com/bizsignup/partner/entry?referralToken=Y2M1ZGYxNTktNjI1Yi00MjIyLTkyNGEtMjc5OTYwODhhMzVhM3docmVUUHhBSVplekx2VE1qL1Q3NHFvYUVBbTdlSzNHRnJBOEMzNzRrQT12Mg==",
           "rel": "action_url",
           "method": "GET"
       }
   ]
 }

As you can see the referral id is in the link:
https://uri.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals/**ZjcyODU4ZWYtYTA1OC00ODIwLTk2M2EtOTZkZWQ4NmQwYzI3RU12cE5xa0xMRmk1NWxFSVJIT1JlTFdSbElCbFU1Q3lhdGhESzVQcU9iRT0=**

So I'm a bit confused, if someone could tell me what do I need to store in the database for the seller onboarding so that I can use that id when buyers buy from sellers?
This was the payload or json request I sent when getting the "action_url":
        {
    "email": "accountemail@example.com",
    "tracking_id": "TRACKING-ID",
    "operations": [{
        "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
        "api_integration_preference": {
            "rest_api_integration": {
                "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
                "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
                "third_party_details": {
                    "features": [
                        "PAYMENT",
                        "REFUND"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    "products": [
        "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"
    ],
    "legal_consents": [{
        "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
        "granted": true
    }]
    }

Also would this way be the way to allow multiple sellers to receive payments as I'm trying to develop a market place for sellers to sell items to buyers?
